# Gatsby page components as class components

Tags: gatsby

I know I ask this on the eve of React Hooks being released but I was wondering - is it possible to create Page components as a Class component instead of a Function component?

When I convert the default Gatsby starter `src/pages/index.js` page to a Class component as such

```js
class IndexPage extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>I am a class component</div>
    )
  }
}

export default IndexPage
```

I get this error `(AppContainer)TypeError: Cannot set property 'props' of undefined`

I couldn't find any documentation on this

Comment: Yeah, that's totally fine - your error is probably coming out of your template I'd bet. Can you post that?

Comment: @staypuftman - so i started to comment out parts of the default `src/components/layout.js` and oddly it just started working after uncommenting out code ‍♂️ (I also upgraded `react` and `react-dom` to 16.8.1

Comment: Gatsby tends to recommend functional components. I'm not 100% sure but it mostly seems to be their standard so you can make use of `Staticquery`. That allows you to make data requests at the component level - very helpful. Using it together with a complicated state model can be very tricky however (think like a shopping cart). Keep building though, it's a great platform over all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in your example code.

```
export default IndexPage
```

instead of `return`